# javascript: correctly get the value of the return statement that is coming from a functioncall of a different class

Tags: javascript, class, return

Here is my code:

```
//in main-class
var mapper = new ImageMapper();
console.log("Snowfall");
var tiles = mapper.cropImage("../../grafiken/webseite/Snowflakes.png");
console.log(tiles);

console.log("ende");

//in ImageMapper-class
cropImage(path) {
this.img.src = path;
    var that = this;
    this.img.onload = function() {
        that.init();

        var tiles = that.getTiles();
        console.log(tiles);
        // that.drawTiles(tiles);

        // console.log("in Mapperclass:");
        console.log(tiles);
        return tiles;
      }
  }
```

[Browserconsole. Array and other outputs are strangely reverse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSzVw.png)

As you can see above, the `console.log` of the returned value gives me `undefined`.

How can I change that so that I get what I want, which is the value that the function returns inside the class itself (in the `functioncall`)?

And why does it first call `console.log("ende")` and after that the array of tiles even though it's in reverse?

[function getTiles()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9pkY.png)

Comment: Hi Leon, you are creating tiles in a callback that's listening to the onload event of the image. The function cropImage doesn't actually return anything. You can return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and resolve it with tiles in the onload function or reject it in the image onError function.

Comment: Could you please check the code after `//in ImageMapper-class` as it does not seem to be valid javascript. Also it would really help is we could see what `getTiles()` does

Comment: @Grassator That part of the code is a method inside `class ImageMapper { ... }`, hence the code is invalid without the entire structure of the class around it.

Comment: @HMR
Thanks for the tip. As it's that I'm still learning, I don't really get what I'm supposed to do then.
Inside the new Promise(_here_) 
do I give it the function mapper.cropImage(location) or is the promise supposed to go completely inside cropImage() ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually return something from inside the cropImage() method and the result from the image.onload() call returns it's results into the void.

A function that does not return anything, gets the value 'undefined'.
So when you log 'tiles', you get the 'undefined' in the console.
So your console.log results are correct.

You probably want the onload function of the image to set a property on the imageMapper instance so you can access it after the image is loaded. And then you have to add a callback ( or promise, or async/await ) to notify the script outside that the mapper has loaded its image.

Do a search for 'how to return from an asynchronous call', since this image loading is basically the same as a manual ajax call for some file.

Answer (score 0):

To have cropImage return a promise can look something like this:

```
cropImage(path) {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve,reject)=>{
      this.img.src = path;
      var that = this;
      this.img.onload = function() {
        that.init();

        var tiles = that.getTiles();
        console.log(tiles);
        // that.drawTiles(tiles);

        // console.log("in Mapperclass:");
        console.log(tiles);
        resole(tiles);
      };
      this.img.onerror=reject;
    }
  )
}

//call it later:
mapper.cropImage("../../grafiken/webseite/Snowflakes.png")
.then(
  (tiles)=>console.log('now I have tiles:',tiles)
)
.catch(
  (error)=>console.log('there was an error:',error)
)
```

Comment: Uh, lamda-expressions always kinda scare me ^^'

And that returns me an Array of tiles, that was beforehand created by getTiles() ?
Why can't I just return it? Doesn't the last log show, that it was created?

Comment: @Leon JavaScript functions have to return immediately but the tiles can only be created when the image is loaded (img.onload). So to ask if the function cannot return the tiles is like asking if you can immediately give me the winning numbers of the tomorrows lotto drawing.

Comment: Thank you very much, it kinda works now.
One more question:
As I want the cropped pictures to be a part of an object that I draw an my canvas, how could I make sure that all that happens before my objects get created and rendered?

Comment: @Leon You can render the canvas only when the promise(s) is/are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

`cropImage` actually doesn't return anything. Instead, it "only" contains a event handler, which returns something - but this return value is ignored and got lost.

There are many solutions to your problem. I.e. you could pass a callback function to `cropImage` which is called inside the `load` event. The other option would be to return a `Promise` in `cropImage`, which handles the callback.
Use a callback:

```
cropImage(path, finish) {
    this.img.src = path;
    var that = this;
    this.img.onload = function() {
        that.init();
        var tiles = that.getTiles();
        finish(tiles);
    }
}


cropImage('...', function(tiles) {
    console.log(tiles);
}
```

second option with a `Promise`:

```
cropImage(path, finish) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        this.img.src = path;
        var that = this;
        this.img.onload = function() {
            that.init();
            var tiles = that.getTiles();
            resolve(tiles);
        }
    });
}

// cropImage with a promise
cropImage('...').then(function(tiles) {
    console.log(tiles);
});
```

Comment: We probably wrote the answer at the same time. If there is something wrong with the image loading the promise is never resolved and the callback is never called. You should handle img.onerror as well.